# Minimal grub for Ubuntu 20.04 iso image

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I tried to boot ubuntu 20.04 in my dell inspiron 15 5000 laptop from iso image burned into a usb pendrive.
But grub appears to be in minimal setup with only the command line with no menu at all. What could be the problem? How can I solve? Tell me if you need more information about my pc. Currently I have installed ubuntu 18.04.

P.S.
My laptop bios is a uefi bios.

UPDATE:
This is a [bug of grub 2.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311) I'm waiting they solve it

Comment: What's "usb image"? Where does it come from?

Comment: @mikewhatever I downloaded it from https://www.ubuntu-it.org/download that is the official site for official iso image of ubuntu in italian

Comment: So..., are usb image and ISO image the same in Italian? I've never heard of usb images before. In case it is an ISO image after all, the way you write it is important. You might want to expand on that.

Comment: I burned the official iso image into a usb pendrive with the ubuntu tool

Comment: I corrected the post.

Comment: Make sure you are using grub 2.02, not grub 2.04. 2.04 Out of memory error loop mount
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311

Comment: I use the official version of 20.04 image that is the 2.04 version of grub, but can I change it? How?

Comment: Same here: downloaded 20.04 iso from Ubuntu's website (international version), copied the image on USB with Rufus, fresh install, resulted in minimal grub.